# Javascript canvas change drawing color

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a simple drawing board with HTML and JavaScript (Node as server side), but I don't know how I can make a colorpicker where I change the color of the paint. I know how to hard code it, but that is not what I want.

I want something like buttons, if you click a button it will turn into a specific color. Something like 4 buttons.

This is my method:

```
 //Function for when the mouse button is clicked.
canvas.onmousedown = function (e) {
    //The mouse button is clicked (true).
    mouse.click = true;
    context.strokeStyle = "red";
};
```

As you can see, I have hardcoded the color to red.

This is my full JavaScript code. The HTML document only consist of an element "canvas".

```
//"DOMContetLoaded tells the browser then the HTML page has finished loading.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    //Add standard mouse functions.
    var mouse = {
        click: false,
        move: false,
        pos: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        pos_prev: false
    };

    //Get the CanvasWhiteboard elements by it's ID from the HTML page. We need this to be able to draw.
    var canvas = document.getElementById('whiteboard');
    //The whiteboard is in 2D with the width and height being the dimensions of the window.
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    //The client connects to the server.
    var socket = io.connect();

    //The width and height of the whiteboard equals the window width and height.
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    // Function for when the mouse button is pushed down.
    canvas.onmousedown = function (e) {
        // Set mouse click to true.
        mouse.click = true;
        context.strokeStyle = "red";
    };

    // Function for when the mouse button is lifted.
    canvas.onmouseup = function (e) {
        // Set mouse click to false.
        mouse.click = false;
    };

    // Function to check if the mouse is moved.
    canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
        //The movement of the mouse at X and Y position is updated everytime the mouse moves.
        //The coordinates equals the coordinates relative to the window height and width.
        mouse.pos.x = e.clientX / width;
        mouse.pos.y = e.clientY / height;

        //The mouse is moving (true).
        mouse.move = true;
    };

    //Listen for draws from other clients.
    socket.on('draw_data', function (data) {
        //The line being drawn equals the data.
        var line = data.line;

        //Begin from the start of the drawn data.
        context.beginPath();

        //The thickness of the line.
        context.lineWidth = 2;

        //Next point to move to from the beginPath.
        context.moveTo(line[0].x * width, line[0].y * height);

        //End point to move to from the beginPath.
        context.lineTo(line[1].x * width, line[1].y * height);

        //The data is then drawn on the whiteboard.
        context.stroke();
    });

    //This loop is where our own drawings are sent to the server for the other clients to see.
    //It checks every 25ms if the mouse is being clicked and moved.
    function mainLoop() {
        if (mouse.click && mouse.move && mouse.pos_prev) {
            //Send our drawing to the server.
            socket.emit('draw_data', { line: [mouse.pos, mouse.pos_prev] });
            //The mouse movement is set to false (reset).
            mouse.move = false;
        }

        //The previous position now equals the position we just were at.
        mouse.pos_prev = { x: mouse.pos.x, y: mouse.pos.y };

        //This is where the 25ms is definend.
        setTimeout(mainLoop, 25);
    }

    //Being called recursively.
    mainLoop();
});
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken this doesn't have anything to do with `nodeJs`.

Comment: I am sorry you are right, this is javascript I changed the question.

Comment: If you don't want to hardcode the color, where would you like to get the color from?

Comment: If you're asking us to help you to implement a color-picker, this question is too broad (and there might also be related questions on SO that have answers). If you're asking us to recommend a 3rd-party color-picker that is off-topic for SO.

Comment: I want something like buttons, if you click a button it will turn into a specific color. Something like 4 buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution:

In HTML I added a drop down box:

```
 <!--Color Picker-->
<select id="colors">
    <option value="black">black</option>
    <option value="aqua">aqua</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
    <option value="brown">brown</option>
</select>
```

In my JavaScript I added this to get the color picker by ID:

```
//Get the color picker from the HTML page by ID.
var getColorPickerByID = document.getElementById("colors");
```

And this to get the value of the color picker, i.e. the selected item. This should of course be in a loop that updates every like 10ms so the value gets updated when you pick a new color:

```
//Get the color picker value, i.e. if the user picks red the value is red.
var getValueOfColorPicker = getColorPickerByID.options[getColorPickerByID.selectedIndex].text;
```

And at last the strokeStyle itself to set the color of the line being drawn by using the value from the above variable `getValueOfColorPicker`

```
//Set the color of the line being drawn by using above variable "getValueOfColorPicker".
drawingArea.strokeStyle = getValueOfColorPicker;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to do it too, changing the Canvas to red when click the button

```
 canvas{
      background-color:red; 
 }
```

Or try this code:

```
     //Function for when the mouse button is clicked.
canvas.onmousedown = function (e) {
    //The mouse button is clicked (true).
    mouse.click = true;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
};
```

Comment: Sorry it's not the canvas color, it's the drawing color.

Answer (score 0):

I written sample code you can use it.

```js
function changeColor(color) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
};

const c = document.querySelector("#c");
c.height = window.innerHeight / 2;
c.width = window.innerWidth / 2;
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

let painting = false;

function mousedown(e) {
  painting = true;
  mousemove(e);
}

function mouseup() {
  painting = false;
  ctx.beginPath();
}

function mousemove(e) {
  if (!painting) return;
  ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  //ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';

  ctx.lineTo(e.clientX / 2, e.clientY / 2);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(e.clientX / 2, e.clientY / 2);
}
c.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);
c.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
c.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
```

```css
#c {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#container {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  width: 5em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" content="Badri,Chorapalli,XML,JavaScript">
  <title>Canvas</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas><br>
    <button class="button" onclick="changeColor('black')" id="blue">Black</button>
    <button class="button" onclick="changeColor('blue')" id="blue">Blue</button>
    <button class="button" onclick="changeColor('red')" id="blue">Red</button>
    <button class="button" onclick="changeColor('green')" id="blue">Green</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```